# Deployed Bot is working with emulator but not in Web Chat

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

One of the bots I'm working on (using Virtual Assistant Template 4.9.1.1__1) does not work if open from the "Test in Web Chat" pane in Azure.
("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Please try again later.")

I checked all the possible causes listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-does-not-work-in-web-chat) but none of them applies to my situation. In fact the bot is working if called from the bot emulator.

Looking at

```
https://<bot-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/:output
```

or:

```
az webapp log tail -n <bot-name> -g <resource-group-name>
```

and nothing appears.

How can I troubleshoot what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's causing the error: it's the embedded image size (maybe too big).

Replacing:

"url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..."

with:

"url": "https://myurl/myimage.jpg"

solved the issue.

Is there a limit on image size?